# Merge svg with a div in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

I am trying to display a flowchart on a webpage and this loads based on some options selected by the user.I am creating each element of the flow chart in a div and generating them. And after the elements are generated I am trying to draw lines connecting the elements.

But when I do this the lines are appearing below the elements.
Here is my code.

```
 <div class="container">
            <div ng-repeat="x in elements">
                <br/>
                    <div id="{{y.id}}" class="box" ng-click="myfunction($event)" ng-repeat="y in x.matches">{{y.id}}</div>
                <br/>
            </div>


            <svg>
                 <g ng-repeat="line in lineList">
                 <line ng-x1={{line.x1}} ng-y1={{line.y1}} ng-x2={{line.x2}} ng-y2={{line.y2}} style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
                 </g>
           </svg>
</div>
```

I want to draw the lines in the same division the elements are created. Please let me know how this can be done.

Any further information would be provided upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-attr-x1` instead of `ng-x1`:

```
<svg>
    <g ng-repeat="line in lineList">
         <line ng-attr-x1={{line.x1}} ng-attr-y1={{line.y1}} ng-attr-x2={{line.x2}} ng-attr-y2={{line.y2}} style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If I use x1, y1... I get this error "Invalid value for <line> attribute x1:". Let me try with ng-attr. Do I have to create a new directive to use ng-attr

Comment: no. See more about `ngAttr` in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation There is also example for `svg` element